# Prevent opening of Application on browser refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, interop

I have an ASP.NET/C# application that exports some data into an Excel spreadsheet using COM interop at the click of a Button control. When I click the button, Excel is opened with the generated spreadsheet. For what it's worth, here is the button code:

```
<asp:Button ID="export" Text="Export to spreadsheet" runat="server" OnClick="Export_Workbook" />
```

This works fine, except when I click the button, close the subsequent spreadsheet, and refresh the page. When the page is refreshed after clicking the button, the call to `Export_Workbook()` is made again and so the spreadsheet opens again. Firefox, for example, says this when you refresh: "To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier." This is something I want to avoid.

I'm sure there's a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, I'm just not sure what the best approach is.

**Edit**

I've accomplished this by doing the following:

```
protected void Export_Workbook(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsolutePath, false);
    ItemList.Prepare_Workbook();
}
```

Not a particularly elegant solution, but it works. I'm still open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to redirect back to the current page at some point at the end of the postback to prevent duplicate form submission. This is called the [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.

Comment: I tried forcing a postback after the export button is clicked, but this didn't solve the problem. I'm not sure how to go about implementing this design pattern. EDIT: see my updated post above...

Comment: @Tyler, it's going to be a bit more involved in your case since you're streaming data and trying to redirect at the same time. Not sure if this will work, but you could try creating an HTTP Handler which will be responsible for streaming your spreadsheet. Then specify the path to the Http Handler in your button's PostBackUrl property. I think this would do away with the issue without redirects.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a better way to do it, except to keep track of if it has been refreshed before, and just not call the content the second time you refresh it.